# Name of the metric space defined by the Minkowski distance function

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I want to know the name of the metric space defined by the Minkowski distance function

For example..
Euclidean distance function can define euclidean plane
and taxi distance is related to taxicab geometry (?) or taxi plane...
then, what is the name of the plane defined by Minkowski distance funtion...?
Should I call it just Minkowski plane?

Comment: It's usually the 1+1-dimensional Minkowski space.